# Add an incremental number in a field in INSERT INTO SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an `INSERT INTO SELECT` query. In the `SELECT` statement I have a subquery in which I want to add an incremental number in a field. 
This query will work fine if my `SELECT` query and returns only one record, But if it returns multiple rows it inserts the same number in the incremental field for all those rows. 
Is there any way to restrict it to add an incremental number every time?

```
INSERT INTO PM_Ingrediants_Arrangements_Temp 
(AdminID,ArrangementID,IngrediantID,Sequence)
(SELECT 
     @AdminID, @ArrangementID, PM_Ingrediants.ID, 
     (SELECT 
          MAX(ISNULL(sequence,0)) + 1 
      FROM
          PM_Ingrediants_Arrangements_Temp 
      WHERE 
          ArrangementID=@ArrangementID)
FROM 
    PM_Ingrediants 
WHERE 
    PM_Ingrediants.ID IN (SELECT 
                              ID 
                          FROM 
                              GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@IngrediantsIDs))
)
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` function for this.

```
INSERT INTO PM_Ingrediants_Arrangements_Temp(AdminID, ArrangementID, IngrediantID, Sequence)
    SELECT @AdminID, @ArrangementID, PM_Ingrediants.ID,
            row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
    FROM PM_Ingrediants 
    WHERE PM_Ingrediants.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@IngrediantsIDs)
                             )
```

If you want to start with the maximum already in the table then do:

```
INSERT INTO PM_Ingrediants_Arrangements_Temp(AdminID, ArrangementID, IngrediantID, Sequence)
    SELECT @AdminID, @ArrangementID, PM_Ingrediants.ID,
           coalesce(const.maxs, 0) + row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
    FROM PM_Ingrediants cross join
         (select max(sequence) as maxs from PM_Ingrediants_Arrangement_Temp) const
    WHERE PM_Ingrediants.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@IngrediantsIDs)
                             )
```

Finally, you can just make the `sequence` column an auto-incrementing identity column.  This saves the need to increment it each time:

```
create table PM_Ingrediants_Arrangement_Temp ( . . .
    sequence int identity(1, 1) -- and might consider making this a primary key too
    . . .
)
```

Comment: for 3rd option i dont have to make sequence field auto increment. i need to get the existing number from sequence and insert the next incremental number in that column

Comment: Scnerio 2 works in my condition . thank u very much for immediate help.

Comment: :: if my squence column dont allow null values and my table dont have any record already. its throwing exception....

Comment: @SohailHameed . . . If the table is empty, alter the column to be an `identity(1, 1)`.  That is the simplest way to keep it up-to-date.  In any case, I've fixed the query with a `coalesce()` to handle this problem.